# AngularJS data bind shows html

Tags: angularjs

When i attach a scope variable to a div it displays html tags. Trying to solve it.

### Controller

```
$scope.homeBox = response.data[$item];  


<div ng-bind="homeBox" ng-bind-html="myService.body | limitTo: limit"></div>
```

This displays following
[image]

Comment: Why do you have two `bind` attributes on one element? How can you limit html string without breaking valid html?

Comment: @charlietfl  ng-bind-html="myService.body | limitTo: limit"> this one outputs my initial call to content. and then when a button is clicked 
$scope.homeBox = response.data[$item];  
this replaces the initial content with new content.

Comment: can you please fiddle it out the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-bind-html if you have to bind html

```
<div ng-bind-html="homeBox" ng-bind-html="myService.body | limitTo: limit"></div>
```

But you cannot have two ng-bind-html in one tag. First one will dominate. So better use separate div for both.

Answer (score 0):

I found the sollution.
I should not have used two binds.Instead i have used the same bind that i used to initially call contents.

```
$scope.myService.body  = response.data[$item];
```